# Graph API to create multiple image post (carusel feature) on Instagram

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I'm using GRAPH API to publish instagram posts which do work fine:
To store an image:

```
POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/...someid.../media
```

To publish an Instagram post using the image:

```
POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/...someid.../media_publish?creation_id=...someresourceid..."
```

My question is, how can I publish an instagram post containing multiple images that a user can switch between the images with the carusel feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create 2-10 item containers
2. Create a carousel container containing those item containers
3. Publish the carousel container

Full instructions and example: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing#carousel-posts

Comment: Great. Now it's officially added

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at least at the moment this seems to be impossible as the official [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media) states

> Posts with multiple images are not supported

I hope this will change in the future

Answer (score 0):

So far, there has been no update from the Instagram Developer's blog. So, I guess we need to wait longer for this feature to be available.